# Show this derived set is not empty

Tags: general-topology

Let the $f: \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N} \to (\Bbb{Z} ,D)$ by $f(m,n) = m-[{n \over 2}]$

(Here, the $\Bbb{N}$ is set of the natural numbers and the $D$ is a discrete topology on the integers set,$\Bbb{Z}$)

Define the Topological space, $T$ in $\Bbb{Z}$ $s.t.$ $T = \{f^{-1} (G) \vert G \in T\}$

Show the $A' \neq \phi$, ($\forall A \subset \Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N}$ and $A$ is a infinite set.)

---

My attempt) I considered the one point(open set in $Z$) $\ \forall m\ \in Z$

$f^{-1}(m)$ = $(m,1)$ since $m-[{n \over 2}] = m$

$f^{-1}(m-1)$ = $(m,2), (m,3)$ since $m-[{n \over 2}] = m-1$

Observe these facts, then we can induce the open set  has a form that

$\{(m,2k), (m,2k+1)\}$ $[k=1,2,3,....]$

Hence, $T = \{(m,1)\} \cup \ \{(m,2k), (m,2k+1)\}$,$[k=1,2,3,....],(m \in N)$

But the Case $A = \{(m,2k) \vert k=1,2,3,..\} $ is $A' = \phi$.

So Does above question is contradict, Right?

I'm not sure which point I was wrong.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Notice, $f^{-1}(m)\ne (m,1)$ since for example $f(m+1,3)=m$ and so on...

Comment: This definition of $T$ can't possibly be right. Should it say $G\in D,$ instead, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you consider the map $f: \Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \mathbb Z$ defined by $f(m,n)=m-\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ and the induced topology $\mathcal{T}_f$ by $f$ on $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ when $\Bbb Z$ has the discrete topology.

The handiest observation to make is that $(m,2n) \in O$ (for $O$ in that topology), then $(m,2n+1) \in O$ as well and vice versa, as $f(m,2n)= f(m, 2n+1)$ for your $f$, and $O = f^{-1}[O']$ for some $O' \subseteq \Bbb Z$ by the definition of $\mathcal{T}_f$.

So if $A \subseteq \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ with $A \neq \emptyset$ it contains some $(m,n)$ and if $n$ is even, any neighbourhood of $(m,n+1)$ intersects $A$ in at least $(m,n) \neq (m,n+1)$, so $(m,n+1) \in A'$, or $n$ is odd and any neighbourhood of $(m,n-1)$ intersects $A$ in at least $(m,n) \neq (m,n-1)$ so also $(m,n-1) \in A'$.

Note that $A'\neq \emptyset$ always holds, also for finite non-empty sets. The size of $A$ is irrelevant.

This shows that $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ is limit point compact, but it's clearly not countably compact (in the cover sense), as we have a countable disjoint open cover of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ by $\{f^{-1}[\{z\}]: z \in \Bbb Z \}$.

A simpler case of this phenomenon is the product of $\Bbb N$ in the discrete topology by $\{0,1\}$ in the indiscrete (trivial) topology.